# How Replace "a" in $a with Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, dollar-sign

I'm trying to replace the letter "a" in function with a variable. For example, change this:

```
setInterval(function(){         
    var $a = $( '.a' ); 
});
```

to this:

```
var thisClass = 'a';
setInterval(function(){         
    var $(thisClass) = $( '.'+thisClass );  
});
```

The problem is that `= $( '.'+thisClass );` works just fine, but `var $(thisClass)` doesn't. I have tried some variations including: `var $thisClass` and `var $('thisClass')` but none work.

Is it possible to insert/inject a variable in place of the "a" in `$a`?

UPDATE:

Below is the current state of my actual code. I did realize that I could simply replace `$a` with `$( '.a' )` which solves some of my problem of attempting to use the `var` to replace all of the classNames used in my function at once. But I'm still left with `getElementById("a")` at the end which won't work if I use for example `getElementById("classVar")` or `getElementById(classVar)` instead.

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        var classVar = 'a'; 
        $('.'+classVar).makisu( 'toggle' );
            $('.'+classVar).makisu({ 
                selector: 'dd',
                overlap: Math.random() * (.7 - .2) + .2,
                speed: Math.random() * (3 - .2) + .2
            });
    }, document.getElementById("a").childElementCount*universalBoxTime );
```

Comment: Calling `setInterval` without clearing it is going to keep the code inside of it running in an endless loop

Comment: Why would your code depend on the specific name of your variable?

Comment: Hi @Blender, I'm not sure I'm understanding your question, but if it clarifies, my actual project will use many copies of a more complicated similar function. I'm trying to come up with a simple way that, instead of having to change the className reference used a number of times inside the function, I want to simply keep most of the code the same and use the `var =` to switch out all the default classNames with the unique one. Something like ` var uniqueClassName =  defaultClassReferencesInsideFunction;` thus saving me some time when codeing.

Comment: @forestkelley: Why can't you do `var $a = $( '.'+thisClass );` and just use `$a` in your function body?

Comment: @Blender, I just updated my post with my current longer code. I think, in a way, I've done basically what you suggested with `var classVar = 'a';` instead of `var $a = $( '.'+thisClass );`.

Comment: @Blender: The reason I don't want to use $a in the function is that I'm planning to use many copies of this function. And to avoid having to change $a in each subsequent function to, for example, $b and then $c and so on, I want to use the `var` so that I can just change `var a` to `var b` and then not have to change anything else in the function/code. I know this isn't efficient in terms of the code, but it will save me a lot of time as I tinker with this creative project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with scope. In the code that you've posted, `classVar` exists only inside of the `setTimeout` callback and cannot be used outside. In JavaScript, you can create functions that create and call other functions, so you can make your code more generic in this way:

```
function do_the_thing($elements) {
    var delay = $elements.children().length * universalBoxTime;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $elements.makisu('toggle');
        $elements.makisu({ 
            selector: 'dd',
            overlap: Math.random() * (.7 - .2) + .2,
            speed: Math.random() * (3 - .2) + .2
        });
    }, delay);
}

do_the_thing($('.a'));
do_the_thing($('.b'));
```

I used `$elements` instead of `elements` just to make it obvious that `$elements` is a jQuery object. The dollar sign has no significance when used as part of a variable name.

Comment: Awesome! I'm just getting my head around callbacks and this is a great solution. This is even more efficient than what I was trying to do. Thanks!  I didn't realize that my `var classVar = 'a';` would fall out of the scope of the function's delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it by property name as long as you know the parent object.

In your case, it looks like your variable is in the global scope, so you can try to access it from the `window` object:

```
var thisClass = 'a';
setInterval(function(){         
    window['$' + thisClass] = $( '.'+thisClass );  
});
```

If you only need this variable inside your `setInterval` function you can use `this` instead of `window`:

```
var thisClass = 'a';
setInterval(function(){         
    this['$' + thisClass] = $( '.'+thisClass );  
});
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me when I replace `$a` with `this['$' + thisClass]` or `window['$' + thisClass]`. I may need to research those to know more about your suggestion.